# Has the foregroundservice stopped on Android OREO in doze mode state?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner to the Android development, I'm building an Alarm app.
I tried to run the app on any android version (5.0, 4.4, 6.0, 7.0) the alarm still ring on time, but I try to run on Android Oreo 8 (Huawei P20 lite, Sony Xperia XZ1) alarm can't ring. After then, I have to use JobIntentService or foregroundservice so the alarm can ring but not on time at background device.

What's wrong? When setting time for alarm and waiting at background app, alarm ring on time but at background device, alarm still ring but not on time or even alarm not ring? Anyone can find out a solution for this issue?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the android documentation for doze mode.

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

> If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use
>   setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I tried use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() but this still can't help me. When device sleep, alarm still ring but not on time.